# Colorbar from custom colorRampPalette

Tags: r, colors

I have defined a colorRampPalette:

```
my.colors = colorRampPalette(c("light green", "yellow", "orange", "red"))
```

How can I plot a colorbar "legend" item for it, preferably using only the base packages? I am after a rectangle filled with that color gradient.

What I am really after is a way to produce the same type of legend (color bar) that is plotted with a "raster" raster:

```
require(raster)
plot(raster("myfile.tif"), legend=T)
```

I need to be able to place this on top of another plot.

Comment: It's funny how difficult this is to do in base R.  Usually R has so much magic but apparently not for colorbars.  I guess statisticians only think in black and white? haha

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I made a nice flexible function awhile ago to do this.

```
# Function to plot color bar
color.bar <- function(lut, min, max=-min, nticks=11, ticks=seq(min, max, len=nticks), title='') {
    scale = (length(lut)-1)/(max-min)

    dev.new(width=1.75, height=5)
    plot(c(0,10), c(min,max), type='n', bty='n', xaxt='n', xlab='', yaxt='n', ylab='', main=title)
    axis(2, ticks, las=1)
    for (i in 1:(length(lut)-1)) {
     y = (i-1)/scale + min
     rect(0,y,10,y+1/scale, col=lut[i], border=NA)
    }
}
```

Then you can do something like:

```
> color.bar(colorRampPalette(c("light green", "yellow", "orange", "red"))(100), -1)
```

[image]

More examples at: http://www.colbyimaging.com/wiki/statistics/color-bars

Comment: Your axis is nicer than mine. +1.

Comment: If you take out the dev.new you can use subplot from package:Hmisc to overlay this onto existing plots.

Comment: @Spacedman how can you do that? I'm always encountering this error `Error in plot.new() : plot region too large`

Comment: It's kind of unclear to me what "lut" means. The link no longer works.

Answer (score 10):

Make a matrix, use image with some axes parameters...

```
my.colors = colorRampPalette(c("light green", "yellow", "orange", "red"))
z=matrix(1:100,nrow=1)
x=1
y=seq(3,2345,len=100) # supposing 3 and 2345 are the range of your data
image(x,y,z,col=my.colors(100),axes=FALSE,xlab="",ylab="")
axis(2)
```

[image: image legend]

Answer (score 4):

colorbar.plot() from the fields package is a standard solution. Many folks will be looking here for solutions that place the legend outside of the standard plot area or the original x/y range. This limitation of colorbar.plot() is easily overcome by:

1. plotting your image(),
2. expanding the size of the plot device with par(pin = c(width, length))
3. calling colorbar.plot() using original x and y values

Because the area of the plot device is now expanded, the legend will appear outside of the original image() plot. Experimenting with x and y values lands the legend anywhere you wish. The gradient legend can be horizontal or vertical using standard argument options.

Comment: Yes but you also need the 'strip' argument and so far it's not as simple as it should be to figure out.  A working code example is usually part of a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old question, and the answers are all great. I just wanted to point out that you could just smooth the color bar from `levelplot`.

Make some fake data and a color gradient

```
mat = matrix(rnorm(400,1,1), ncol=20)
grad = rev(rainbow(1000, start=rgb2hsv(col2rgb('green'))[1], 
       end=rgb2hsv(col2rgb('blue'))[1]))
```

Make the plot and specify breaks in the color bar

```
levelplot(mat, col.regions=grad, colorkey = list(at=seq(0,max(mat),length.out=400)))
```

This functionality to `levelplot` may have been added long after all you folks came up with sweet workaround solutions.