# How to make a gradual color bar for representation of risk analysis results in R?

Tags: r, plot, colors, colorbar

I want to plot results of risk analysis that categorized by 4 levels (No risk, low, moderate and high risk) on gradual color bar (green-yellow-red).
I thought about something like this (but I'm open for nicer suggestions.)
[image]

The input is something like this

```
results <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = 5,ncol = 0))
results$day <- c(1:5)
results$assessment <-c("Low","Moderate","High","Low","Moderate")
```

Comment: I expect that you could adapt [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9314880/4752675)

Comment: @G5W I'm quite new with R, I checked it and can't figured it out. Maybe you have an idea? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to give a lot of detail with my answer.

I am assuming that you want *just* the colorbar and not the colorbar 
added to some other graph.   That is what is created below.

### 0 Setup

```
library(fields)     ## for the colorbar function

## create the palette
myPalette = colorRampPalette(c("green", "yellow", "orange", "red"))
```

### 1 Create an empty plot.

```
plot(0:1, 0:1, type="n", bty="n", xaxs="i",
    xaxt="n", yaxt="n", xlab="", ylab="")
```

When you run this, you should get an empty plot - no axes,  nothing. 
Both x and y range from 0 to 1.

### 2 Create the color bar

```
colorbar.plot(0.5, 0.05, 1:100, col=myPalette(100),
    strip.width = 0.2, strip.length = 1.1)
```

### 3 Add the axis labels

```
axis(side=1, at=seq(0,1,1/3), tick=FALSE,
    labels=c("No Risk", "Low", "Moderate", "High Risk"))
```

### 4 Add the arrow.

```
arrows(0.7, 0.18, 0.7, 0.1, length=0, lwd=8)
arrows(0.7, 0.18, 0.7, 0.09, length=0.1, lwd=3, angle=45)
```

This is a bit of a hack.  If I made the lines in the arrow thick,
the arrowhead was rather blunt and ugly. So the first `arrows` 
statement makes a thick line with no arrowhead and the second one
uses a thin line and adds a sharp arrowhead.

I have the arrow at 0.7.  Adjust the x values to place it elsewhere.

### Result

[image: Colorbar]