# Gradient colors on axis in R

Tags: r, excel, gradient, axis

I'm currently trying to reproduce some of our graphs in R.
At the moment we use Excel to produce our graphs and 1 of the options in Excel is the use of gradient colors on the axis. I have added some pictures as an example. 
My question is if a similar option is available in R (in ggplot). I can't find any useful information about this issue on the web. Thanks in advance for any response!

Greetings, Erik

!https://ibb.co/drRd8x
!https://ibb.co/jvPbvc

Comment: Hello Erik, please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example to understand how you best ask questions.

Comment: Hey there's already a question with a good workaround to show a gradient in ggplot2: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48686878/ggplot-how-to-set-the-bar-itself-to-be-colored-by-a-color-gradient-green-yel