# Add customised colour ramp as legend

Tags: r, plot, layout, colors, legend

I created six heatmaps with R base graphics using the `image()` function. They show depth on the y-axis and time along the x-axis. The z values are temperatures. Additionally you can see some contour lines with labels indicating temperature in °C. 
[image]
As each plot comes from a different data frame with a slightly different temperature range, I had to ensure the same colours are used to display temperature in a consistent way. Therefore I customised a colour scale `cols` showing low temperatures towards the blue end and high temperatures at the red end. For each of the six data frames, I aligned their min and max temperatures at predefined max and min values of `cols`. See below the code exemplary for the upperleft data frame RW1-iBA.

```
# Customise colour scale    
RColorBrewer::display.brewer.all()
cols = rev(colorRampPalette(RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(11,"RdYlBu"))(2000))

# Define temperature range for cols
min.cols.temp <- -23
max.cols.temp <- 23

# Define min and max temperatures for RW1-iBA
max_temp <- max(RW1_iBA$temp)
min_temp <- min(RW1_iBA$temp)

# Align RW1-iBA along cols
lowerend.RW1_iBA <- round(min_temp/min.cols.temp*1000)
upperend.RW1_iBA <- round(max_temp/max.cols.temp*1000)
trunc.low.RW1_iBA <- 1000-lowerend.RW1_iBA
trunc.upp.RW1_iBA <- 1001+upperend.RW1_iBA
col.RW1_iBA <- cols[-c(1:trunc.low.RW1_iBA, trunc.upp.RW1_iBA:2000)]
```

What I did here is basically setting upper and lower ends of `cols` to 23 and -23, respectively, making sure these values represent the full range of temperatures for all data frames. Then, I aligned temperature values for each data frame individually along the colour scale by cutting out parts of `cols` that exceed the data frame's max and fall short of its min temperature value, respectively. This gives me six different colour scales (above: `col.RW1_iBA`) that I used for plotting each data frame individually.

What I am missing now is `cols` added to the plot as a legend. The scale itself looks like this:

```
plot(rep(1, 2000), col = cols, pch = 16)
```

[image]
I set up the six plots above with a layout matrix as follows:

```
layoutMatrix
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    7
[2,]    2    5    7
[3,]    3    6    7
```

Spots 1 to 6 are occupied by the six plots you can see above. The margin for column 3 (containing "plot" 7) is already set smaller and I would like to add `cols` as a legend vertically in it. At best it has tick marks and lables for temperature values 20, 10, 0, -10, -20 and a heading like Temperatures (°C). Any idea how I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a piece of code that may help:

```
mat = cbind(1:3, 4:6, 7)
layout(mat, width = c(1,1,.25))
pal =  colorRampPalette(c("white", "black"))(100)
# empty plots
for (i in 1:6) image(matrix(runif(100), 10), col = pal)
# color scale
par(las=1, mar = c(4, 1, 4, 5))
image(t(1:100), col = pal, axes = F, ann = F)
axis(4)
par(las=0)
mtext(4, text = "new_ylab", line = 3)
```

You may have to tweak the margins!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, figured it out with the help of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9314658/colorbar-from-custom-colorramppalette) that uses a customised function to plot scales. I just had to remove the `dev.new()` call to avoid plotting the colour scale in a new device. The function is flexible but you still need to play around with the `par(mar = c())` parameter to adjust width and height of the vertical bar.