# Create colour bar by plotting value and colour

Tags: r, plot, colors, colorbar

I've created my own colour scale by assigning values a particular colour as follows: (Dataframe = df_avg, values column = pmplot, colour column = gr_colour)

```
df_avg$gr_colour[df_avg$pmplot<5] <- "palegreen4"
df_avg$gr_colour[df_avg$pmplot>=5 & df_avg$pmplot<10] <- "palegreen3"
df_avg$gr_colour[df_avg$pmplot>=10 & df_avg$pmplot<12] <- "palegreen2"
df_avg$gr_colour[df_avg$pmplot>=12 & df_avg$pmplot<14] <- "palegreen1"
df_avg$gr_colour[df_avg$pmplot>=14 & df_avg$pmplot<16] <- "lightgoldenrod1"
df_avg$gr_colour[df_avg$pmplot>=16 & df_avg$pmplot<18] <- "khaki1"
df_avg$gr_colour[df_avg$pmplot>=18 & df_avg$pmplot<20] <- "goldenrod1"
df_avg$gr_colour[df_avg$pmplot>=20 & df_avg$pmplot<22] <- "darkgoldenrod1"
df_avg$gr_colour[df_avg$pmplot>=22 & df_avg$pmplot<24] <- "darkorange1"
df_avg$gr_colour[df_avg$pmplot>=24 & df_avg$pmplot<26] <- "darkorange2"
df_avg$gr_colour[df_avg$pmplot>=26 & df_avg$pmplot<28] <- "orangered1"
df_avg$gr_colour[df_avg$pmplot>=28 & df_avg$pmplot<30] <- "orangered3"
df_avg$gr_colour[df_avg$pmplot>=30] <- "red3"
```

Each PM_value has a corresponding Latitude and Longitude value, which I want to plot as dots along a ggmap. The start of my dataframe looks like this:

```
Lat            Long           PM_value      colour
-33.92426      151.2280       19.6          goldenrod1
-33.92406      151.2278       16.8          khaki1
-33.92386      151.2278       13.1          palegreen1
```

I am currently plotting this map as follows:

```
map = get_map(location = c(lon = 151.22528, lat = -33.91413), zoom = 15, maptype = "roadmap")

ggmap(map) + geom_point(data = df_avg, aes(x = df_avg$Long, y = df_avg$Lat), col = df_avg$gr_colour, cex = 4)
```

I want to create a colour bar with the legend corresponding to the PM_values, and the colour bar corresponds to the matching colours (in column 'colour').

So far I have created a gradient of the colours as follows:

```
colfunc <- colorRampPalette(c("palegreen4", "palegreen3", "palegreen2", "palegreen1", "lightgoldenrod1","khaki1", "goldenrod1", "darkgoldenrod1", "darkorange1", "darkorange2", "orangered1", "orangered3"))

plot(rep(1,100),col=colfunc(100),pch=15,cex=3)
```

How do I create a colour bar in this ggmap to match the colours with the appropriate values in 'PM_value'?

Comment: Is something like this what you're after? [colorbar from custom colorramppalette](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9314658/colorbar-from-custom-colorramppalette)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this?

```
library(tidyverse)
pal <- c("palegreen4", "palegreen3", "palegreen2", "palegreen1", "lightgoldenrod1","khaki1", "goldenrod1", "darkgoldenrod1", "darkorange1", "darkorange2", "orangered1", "orangered3","red3")
Breaks <- c(0,5,seq(10,30,2))
set.seed(123)
tibble(PM_value=sample(1:50, 500, T)) %>% 
  mutate(col=cut(PM_value, breaks = c(0,5,seq(10,30,2), max(PM_value)), labels = c(0,5,seq(10,30,2)))) %>% 
  mutate(col=as.numeric(as.character(col))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=seq_along(PM_value),y=PM_value, color=col)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    scale_colour_gradientn(colors = pal, values=scales::rescale(c(0,5,seq(10,30,2))))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Jimbou, thanks for your comment! That code works perfectly - however I am trying to plot on a map (ggmap), and I'm unable to edit that code to work on a map. I've edited my question to provide some more details - do you know how you would use that code to plot on the ggmap?