# How to assign a maximum value shown on a colour ramp in R

Tags: r, plot, color-palette

This is probably a simple thing to do in R, but I want to set a maximum value shown on a predefined colour ramp. I've been asked to use cmocean colour palettes and have a numeric variable with values ranging from 0 to ~10. However, I want the darkest colour to apply to values => 5. For example, any value of 5 and above will be displayed as the same/ "maximum" colour available. I don't want to remove the data above 5 so subsetting isn't an option. I hope this makes sense, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is at least one way to do this, see if this approach works for your use-case:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(palmerpenguins)
#install.packages("cmocean")
library(cmocean)
library(cowplot)
library(ggbeeswarm)

plot_1 <- penguins %>% 
  na.omit() %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = species, y = flipper_length_mm, color = body_mass_g)) +
  geom_quasirandom()  +
  scale_color_cmocean(name = "deep")

plot_2 <- penguins %>% 
  na.omit() %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = species,
             y = flipper_length_mm,
             color = body_mass_g)) +
  geom_quasirandom()  +
  scale_color_cmocean(name = "deep",
                      limits = c(2500, 4000),
                      oob = scales::squish,
                      labels = c("2500", "3000", "3500", "4000+"))
cowplot::plot_grid(plot_1, plot_2, labels = "AUTO")
```

Explanation: Panel "A" (plot_1) doesn't have scale limits, Panel "B" (plot_2) has scale limits. The `oob` option ("Out Of Bounds) is also needed in addition to the scale limits in Panel "B" to 'keep' the darkest colour, otherwise the colours above 4000 are grey. I also altered the labels on the legend (`labels` option) to change "4000" to "4000+", but up to you whether you think that's useful or not.

[image: example.png]

Comment: Thanks for the response, this worked for me! But I just want to confirm that it isn't getting rid of anything above 4000 (for your example), it's just assigning the darkest colour to those values? I only ask because my plots before and after using your method look very similar.

Comment: It isn't getting rid of anything, it's just labelling points >4000 as the darkest shade of the colour scale. If you did want to get rid of points >4000, you can use a 'filter', e.g. `penguins %>% filter(flipper_length <= 4000) %>% ggplot(...`

Answer (score 1):

I guess something like this? You cut the values according to a defined breaks, and in your case, 5 to 10 is 1 break and you assign one color to it:

```
library(cmocean)
x = sort(runif(100,0,10))
pal = cmocean("balance")(11)
lbl = cut(x,breaks = c(seq(0,5,length.out=10),10),right=FALSE)
names(pal) = unique(lbl)
```

Plot it, using the code from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9314658/colorbar-from-custom-colorramppalette) for a colorbar:

```
layout(matrix(c(1,2),ncol=2),widths=c(5,1))

plot(values,rep(1,length(values)),col=pal[lbl],pch=20)

my.colors = pal
z=matrix(1:10,nrow=1)
y=seq(0,5,len=10)
image(1,y,z,col=pal,axes=FALSE,xlab="",ylab="")
axis(2)
```

[image]