# How make a bar color legend for this data in igraph R

Tags: r, colors, igraph

I want make a color bar legend for show what gradient color represent (0 blue a 100% red) in my data. I don't know how make this.

Here's an example of what I want:

[image]

This is code for my data, I assigned colors to nodes according to normalized estimate_betweenness from 0 to 100:

[image]

but I need make a bar color gradient for this.

```
# sample data
library(igraph)
set.seed(62)
N <- 7
fakecors <- runif(choose(N, 2))
cormat <- matrix(nrow = N, ncol = N)
cormat[lower.tri(cormat)] <- fakecors
diag(cormat) <- 0
cormat[upper.tri(cormat)] <- t(cormat)[upper.tri(t(cormat))] 
matrixnetwork <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(cormat, mode = "undirected", weighted = TRUE)


V(matrixnetwork)$eb <- estimate_betweenness(matrixnetwork,cutoff = 0) #$vector hist(matrixnetwork$eb)

# You could use the scales package, or define this normalisation function:
normalize <- function(x){(x-min(x))/(max(x)-min(x))} #Normaliza
(V(matrixnetwork)$eb_index <- round(normalize(V(matrixnetwork)$eb) * 90) + 10) #Coloca em escala de         100%

#eb_index should now be a category between 1 and 100 for your centralities
# Build a color-mapping with 10 categories and set the color of each
# node to the corresponding color of each centrality-measure category
V(matrixnetwork)$color <- colorRampPalette(c("#4477AA","#BB4444"))(100)[V(matrixnetwork)$eb_index]
plot(matrixnetwork)
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: here is a example with graph object , you can apply the above code before and then apply the above code
 library(igraph)
set.seed(62)

N <- 7
fakecors <- runif(choose(N, 2))
cormat <- matrix(nrow = N, ncol = N)
cormat[lower.tri(cormat)] <- fakecors
diag(cormat) <- 0
cormat[upper.tri(cormat)] <- t(cormat)[upper.tri(t(cormat))]

matrixnetwork <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(cormat, mode = "undirected", weighted = TRUE)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the color.bar function from [this existing answer]([Colorbar from custom colorRampPalette](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9314658/colorbar-from-custom-colorramppalette0). You can compose it with your graph using `layout`. For example

```
color.bar <- function(lut, min, max=-min, nticks=11, ticks=seq(min, max, len=nticks), title='') {
  scale = (length(lut)-1)/(max-min)
  
  plot(c(0,10), c(min,max), type='n', bty='n', xaxt='n', xlab='', yaxt='n', ylab='', main=title)
  axis(2, ticks, las=1)
  for (i in 1:(length(lut)-1)) {
    y = (i-1)/scale + min
    rect(0,y,10,y+1/scale, col=lut[i], border=NA)
  }
}
color.bar(colorRampPalette(c("#4477AA","#BB4444"))(100), 0, 100)

layout(matrix(c(1,2), nrow=1), widths=c(2,1))
plot(matrixnetwork)
color.bar(colorRampPalette(c("#4477AA","#BB4444"))(100), 0, 100)
```

[image: igraph with legend]

You can tweak the labels and sizes however you like.

Comment: This is perfect! THANKS!